# The operation failed error while getting inspector.WordEditor as Word.Document in Outlook 365 VSTO C#

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am trying to input some predefined text into a New email in Outlook 365 using VSTO C#. I have written this basic code:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector +=
        new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
    }


    void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {

        try
        {
            if (this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
            {
                if (Inspector.CurrentItem is Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    Word.Document wordDocument = Inspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
                    Word.Range wordRange = wordDocument.Range(0, 0);
                    wordRange.Text = "Text";

                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

While debugging, at line: Word.Document wordDocument = Inspector.WordEditor as Word.Document;
I am getting error "The Operation failed".

[image: Exception details]

I checked Inspector.WordEditor using Outlook spy also and it has data too.

[image: Outlook Spy data]

The same expression is working correct when I craete mailitem by myself using:

```
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = (new Outlook.Application()).CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

I searched on internet a lot, but nothing found something workable in for my case.

I want to know why this is happening and how I can solve this. Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The inspector might not be initialized yet by the time `NewInspector` handler is called. Try to wait until `Inspector.Activate` event fires for the very first time (it can fire multiple times).